# How do I display a pgm/ppm file in html?

Tags: javascript, html, image, pgm

I have a simple pgm file, which I think is the same as a ppm file.

```
P3

5 5
10

1 2 3 4 10
1 10 3 2 5
10 2 4 2 1
0 0 0 0 0
10 10 10 10 10
```

I want to display this file in an HTML document. Right now I have tried using the img tag and an iframe. I want this to display the actual image and not the text. I would like it to be HTML but I can also use javascript.

Comment: Please look at the question I have already stated both of these but here they are again. I have tried using an img and iframe tag. I want it to display a pgm image if you need more info on this [look here.](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll first need to read the contents of the pgm/ppm file. Then loop through the pixel data of the PPM file, which should already have the RGB values. Then you could use `putImageData` on the html5 canvas context.

**Canvas Pixel Manipulation Examples**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas

**PBM/PPM/PGB Format Specs**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format

Answer (score 0):

Use the canvas element `<canvas>` and the canvas API. You can use a 1x1 rectangle to draw pixel by pixel.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API for a starting documentation.